# Common technique in cleaning cache with php infinite loop

Tags: php

Hi the question is when you are executing infinite loop with php, how do you control memory clean up ?
The rough example is to get the result or to update the result from / to mysql in infinity while loop.

Need any common methods .
Thank you.

PS - all the nemesis and bugs of PHP were replaced by moving to python completely ...

Comment: `mysql_free_result`, `unset()`

Comment: I figured out the best methodics to run background python processes , but there should be some common method in cleaning up the memory in php also. mysql_free_result, unset() not helps in most of the cases when you need constant static process running on server background.

Comment: r u intend to create a daemon using php? php memory issue is on compiling scripts into binary, use APC to allow opcode cache

Comment: this is a really nice example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know in PHP memory is freed when variable goes out of scope. But there are some other problems:

1. circullar references - PHP 5.3
   should solve it - it also allows to run GC when you want
2. If PHP takes for example 5 MB of
   memory in first iteration its
   process will occupy this memory even
   if later iterations would take for
   example 1 MB
3. You have to free some things
   manually (like for example mentioned
   before database results)

Using scripting language for process-like running is very bad idea.

Try do it other way:

1. Write a script which would processs
   amount of data that it would take
   approximately 55-60 seconds to run.
2. Add a cron job to run it every
   minute.
3. Add some kind of mutual exclusion to
   script so cron would not run
   concurrent scripts - you can
   synchronise it on database table
   (using SELECT FOR UPDATE)

Comment: Write a script which would processs amount of data that it would take approximately 55-60 seconds to run.  - If I have pretty big one running more than 55-60 seconds about 10 minutes .. it was my old try , GC seems to be good for it , I can't configure my centos server with latest version of php yet , I think I will go deeper with python execution ..

Comment: Entire script runs for 10 minutes? Can't you divide it for 10 smaller cron jobs?

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP 5.3, you can explicitly trigger a GC cycle with `gc_collect_cycles()` as documented [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php).

Before that, it was out of your control, and you'd have to wait for PHP to decide it was time to take out the trash on its own - either by trying to exceed the memory limit with a significant amount of used-but-unattached memory objects or sacrificing a goat under the full moon and hoping for the best.